# Play framework и тестирование router

Tags: scala, playframework

При выполнении теста я прохожу весь флоу от контроллера до базы. Мне это не нужно. Можно ли при помощи Mockito, или других подобных утилит, замокать сервис при тестировании роута?

```scala
    "respond to the index Action" in new App(applicationWithRouter) {
      val Some(result) = route(app, FakeRequest(GET_REQUEST, "/Bob"))

      status(result) mustEqual OK
      contentType(result) mustEqual Some("text/html")
      contentAsString(result) must include("Hello Bob")
    }
```

В роут я передаю application с реальными сервисами. Есть возможность замокать (реализовав свой app с переопределенными классами сервисов), имплементировав этот же трейт, только с заведомо известными ответами.

```scala
val application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .overrides(bind[Component].to[MockComponent])
  .build()
```

Но тогда придется на каждый подобный сервис писать тестовую имплементацию. Но тогда не будет удобно снимать метрики и хитро мокать. Собственно, как замокать непосредственно объект?
Можно замокать так mock[Service], но как его заинжектить в app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в приложении мало компонентов, то можно создать mock-компонент с помощью любой удобной либы (я использую [ScalaMock](https://scalamock.org/)) и заинжектить как вы написали:

```scala
class TestSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with OneInstancePerTest with MockFactory {
  val mockComponent: Component = mock[Component]

  override def fakeApplication(): Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(
      bind[Component].to(mockComponent)
    ).build()
}
```

Если в приложении много компонентов, то я предпочитаю тестировать каждый контроллер отдельно без помощи `fakeApplication`:

```scala
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test.FakeRequest

trait Service {
  def getResource(): Future[JsObject]
}

class Controller @Inject()(
                            service: Service,
                            components: ControllerComponents,
                          ) extends CustomAbstractController(components) {
  def getResource(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    service.getResource().map(resource => Ok(resource))
  }
}

class ControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with MockFactory with OneInstancePerTest {
  private val mockService: Service = mock[Service]
  private createController(): Controller = new Controller(mockService, stubControllerComponents())

  "Controller" should {
    "get resource" in {
      (mockService.getResource _).expect().returning(Future.successful(JsObject.empty))
      val controller = createController()
      val futureResult = controller.getResource().apply(FakeRequest())
      val result = contentAsJson(futureResult).as[JsObject]
      result mustBe JsObject.empty
    }
  }
}
```